# PhotoCatureDevice.SetCaptureResolutionAsync crashing on Lumia 1020 while working 820

Tags: c#, windows-phone, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

There are 3 lines of code that work fine on my 820, but crash on a Lumia 1020:

```
var captureResolutions = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
var captureResolution = captureResolutions.First();
await _cameraEffect.PhotoCaptureDevice.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(captureResolution);
```

As you can see, I first get the avilable resolutions, select the first one (which is, at least using the debugger, the hightest possible resoltion exposed on the PhotoCaptureDevice by default, both on the 820 and the 1020, and finally set the capture resoltion.

As said, it works fine on the 820, but on the 1020, it crashes without any error message - even though, of course, I have attatched the debugger! It also doesn't trigger any breakpoints after that line.

When I leave out the last line and just capture without changing the reolution, everything works fine, but it only has 640x480 resolution (and that's of, course, far too low)

Comment: 820 has 8mp cam. 1020 has 41mp. Maybe It's about that -really- giant camera, and its mp?